# Comparing two excel files for differences

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, excel, csv

I want to compare two input csv files to see if there were rows that were added or removed. What is the best way to go about this. I am not using column names because the names of the columns are not consistent for all files.

```
private void compare_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string firstFile = firstExcel_txt.Text;
            var results = ReadExcel(openFileDialog1);
            string secondFile = secondExcel_txt.Text;
            var results2 = ReadExcel(openFileDialog2);

        }
```

Reading:

```
public object ReadExcel(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
        {
            var _excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(openFileDialog.FileName);
            var _info = from c in _excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader() select c;
            string header1, header2, header3;
            foreach (var item in _info)
            {
                header1 = item.ElementAt(0);
                header2 = item.ElementAt(1);
                header3 = item.ElementAt(2);
            }
            return _info;
        }
```

any help on how i could do that would be great.

Comment: Best and most accurate way would be to convert them both to byte arrays and compare them when they are both converted. Following link will help you converting excel sheets to byte array: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/convert-file-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-files/

Comment: Masriyah you only have 3 columns or you just simplified your code ? I dont see where are you keeping the contents of the excel files to perform the comparison

Comment: Or you could discard the columns and hash the rest. If the hashes for both files match, then they have the same data, verbatim. There is a small chance of hash collision depending on the algorithm used, but it's so small that hell will freeze before you get a collision.

Comment: @MauricioGracia yes i simplified columns for this post - how can keep the content of the excel files?

Comment: @Masriyah I just added and answer that shows an approach to both storing and comparing the text content of the excel files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you **calculate a Hash for each row** of the excel file, then you can go ahead and compare the hash of each row to see if it matches any hash on the other file (see comments in source code)

I have also provided some classes to store the contents of your Excel files

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private void compare_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstFile = firstExcel_txt.Text;
    ExcelInfo file1 = ReadExcel(openFileDialog1);

    string secondFile = secondExcel_txt.Text;
    ExcelInfo file2 = ReadExcel(openFileDialog2);

    CompareExcels(file1,file2) ;
}    

public void CompareExcels(ExcelInfo fileA, ExcelInfo fileB)
{
    foreach(ExcelRow rowA in fileA.excelRows)
    {
        //If the current hash of a row of fileA does not exists in fileB then it was removed 
        if(! fileB.ContainsHash(rowA.hash))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row removed" + rowA.ToString());
        }
    }

    foreach(ExcelRow rowB in fileB.excelRows)
    {
        //If the current hash of a row of fileB does not exists in fileA then it was added 
        if(! fileA.ContainsHash(rowB.hash))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row added" + rowB.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public Class ExcelRow
{
    public List<String> lstCells ;
    public byte[] hash

    public ExcelRow()
    {
        lstCells = new List<String>() ;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string resp ;

        resp = string.Empty ;

        foreach(string cellText in lstCells)
        {
            if(resp != string.Empty)
            {
                resp = resp + "," + cellText ;
            }
            else
            {
                resp = cellText ;
            }   
        }
        return resp ;
    }       
    public void CalculateHash()
    {
        byte[] rowBytes ;
        byte[] cellBytes ;
        int pos ;
        int numRowBytes ;

        //Determine how much bytes are required to store a single excel row
        numRowBytes = 0 ;
        foreach(string cellText in lstCells)
        {
            numRowBytes += NumBytes(cellText) ;
        }       

        //Allocate space to calculate the HASH of a single row

        rowBytes= new byte[numRowBytes]
        pos = 0 ;

        //Concatenate the cellText of each cell, converted to bytes,into a single byte array
        foreach(string cellText in lstCells)
        {
            cellBytes = GetBytes(cellText) ;
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(cellBytes, 0, rowBytes, pos, cellBytes.Length);
            pos = cellBytes.Length ;

        }

        hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(rowBytes);

    }
    static int NumBytes(string str)
    {
        return str.Length * sizeof(char);
    }

    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumBytes(str)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
}
public Class ExcelInfo
{
    public List<ExcelRow> excelRows ;

    public ExcelInfo()
    {
        excelRows = new List<ExcelRow>();
    }
    public bool ContainsHash(byte[] hashToLook)
    {
        bool found ;

        found = false ;

        foreach(ExcelRow eRow in excelRows)
        {
            found = EqualHash(eRow.hash, hashToLook) ;

            if(found)
            {
                break ;
            }
        }

        return found ;
    }
    public static EqualHash(byte[] hashA, byte[] hashB)
    {
        bool bEqual ;
        int i ;

        bEqual  = false;
        if (hashA.Length == hashB.Length)
        {
            i = 0;
            while ((i < hashA.Length) && (hashA[i] == hashB[i]))
            {
                i++ ;
            }
            if (i == hashA.Length)
            {
                bEqual = true;
            }
        }
        return bEqual ;
    }
}

public ExcelInfo ReadExcel(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
{
    var _excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(openFileDialog.FileName);
    var _info = from c in _excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader() select c;

    ExcelRow excelRow ;
    ExcelInfo resp ;

    resp = new ExcelInfo() ;

    foreach (var item in _info)
    {
        excelRow = new ExcelRow() ;

        //Add all the cells (with a for each)
        excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(0));
        excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(1));
        ....
        //Add the last cell of the row
        excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(N));

        //Calculate the hash of the row
        excelRow.CalculateHash() ;

        //Add the row to the ExcelInfo object
        resp.excelRows.Add(excelRow) ;
    }
    return resp ;
}
```

Comment: for my return in the ReadExcel method `return _info` it is throwing an error that i am missing a cast and cannot convert from linq IQuerable to ExcelInfo (ExcelFileReader).

Comment: @Masriyah sorry about that you need to "return resp;"

Comment: When i ran the could i got a null reference exception in my ReadExcel method at `excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(0))` and the error message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Masriyah the code that I posted was not compiled, it was quickly written in notepad++, good to know that the main idea helped

Comment: No problem - Is there a way that i could actually show what records has been removed or added when comparing the two files in the calculate hash method?

Comment: @Masriyah do that on the CompareExcels method. Do a foreach on each ExcelRow of fileA, if the hash of the current row does not exist in the fileB, the you can show that row as been removed. Then do a foreach on each ExcelRow of fileB, if the has of the current row does not exis int fileA, then you can show that row as added.

Comment: Ok thanks i will go ahead with that. Also i just looked over this can the Except Operator be used in this case?

Comment: @Masriyah I just implemented the CompareExcels method, take a look at the source code again

Comment: When i ran the code i would get `ExcelFileReader.ExcelRow` for rowA.toString()

Comment: Did you included the ToString() method that I added ? If you did place a breakpoint inside that method and see what is happening there

Comment: I missed that thanks. but i have to adjust the if statement because currently it is showing each row in the file as it was removed.

Comment: @Masriyah create two excel files with the same identical row and check that the hash is the same, you can show the content "hash" in the ToString method of the ExcelRow class

Comment: the issue seems here: ` while ((i < hashA.Length) && (hashA[i] == hashB[i]))` the `(hashA[i] == hashB[i])` is false even though both are the same.

Comment: @Masriyah that piece of the hash comparison was taken from here - How to compute and compare hash values by using Visual C#http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020/en-us

Comment: yes i looked over that - i changed the while statement in the compareFiles method to this: `while ((i < fileB.excelRows.Count()) && (fileB.excelRows[i].rowHash.SequenceEqual(fileA.excelRows[i].rowHash)))` but because the one i mentioned in my previous comment they are byte[] i am not sure if i could do the same thing

Comment: Keep working on that I have provided 95% of what you need without a compiler, I bet you can manage to detect what is wrong or missing

Answer (score 0):

Most accurate way would be to convert them both to [byte arrays](http://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array), check for differences when both are converted to an array, use following link for a simple *example* on how to *convert excel sheets* to a [byte arrays](http://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array):

[Convert Excel to Byte[]](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/convert-file-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-files/)

Now you have converted both of your excel sheets to a byte[], you should check them for differences by checking if the byte arrays are equal yes or no.

The check can be done by several ways like the following using `linq`:

```
using System.Linq; //SequenceEqual

 byte[] FirstExcelFileBytes = null;
 byte[] SecondExcelFileBytes = null;

 FirstExcelFileBytes = GetFirstExcelFile();
 SecondExcelFileBytes = GetSecondExcelFile();

 if (FirstExcelFileBytes.SequenceEqual<byte>(SecondExcelFileBytes) == true)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Arrays are equal");
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Arrays don't match");
 }
```

There are enough other ways to find compare *byte arrays*, you should do some research about which will suit you best.

Use the following link, to check for things like `Row added`, `row removed` etc.

[Compare excelsheets](http://vkrishnagm.blogspot.in/2010/02/compare-two-excel-sheets.html)

Comment: I am sure this will be of great help. I was looking more into returning something like a row was added or deleted - is that something possible?

Comment: Help link is in answer to achieve that, comparing byte arrays will return true or false

Comment: this approach won't  always work for xlsx.
An XLSX file is a Zip File which contains modification date. That why it is possible to have 2 differents binaries arrays of the files, but they still represent the equal content

Answer (score -1):

I was recently working on the same problem statement, where I had to compare two Excel files and print any differences between the two files.

I adopted the approach of exporting both Excel files to a DataTable and then comparing them cell by cell.

C# code snippet using Syncfusion.XlsIO:

```
public static DataTable SaveExcelToDataTable(string filePath)
{
    //Create an instance of ExcelEngine
    ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();

    //Initialize application
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Xlsx;

    //Open existing workbook with data entered
    FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream);

    //Access first worksheet from the workbook instance
    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    //Export Excel to DataTable
    DataTable dataTable = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames);

    return dataTable;
}

public static bool CompareDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{

    if (dt1.Rows.Count != dt2.Rows.Count || dt1.Columns.Count != dt2.Columns.Count)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < dt1.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            if (!Equals(dt1.Rows[i][c], dt2.Rows[i][c]))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There's no mention of an `ExcelEngine`, `IWorkbook `, `ExportDataTable`, etc. in the question. Nobody knows what happens here.