# Showing records of added or removed items from file comparison

Tags: c#

I am comparing two csv files and distinguishing whether records have been added or removed. I am able to know if items have been added or removed but i want to show what were the records that were inserted or removed. I had a different yet related post that Mauricio Gracia has helped a lot [Comparing two excel files for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452660/comparing-two-excel-files-for-differences/18453551?noredirect=1#18453551)

```
 if (fileB.excelRows.Count() < fileA.excelRows.Count())
                    {
                        string result = "";
                        foreach (ExcelRow rowA in fileA.excelRows)
                        {

                            if (!fileB.ContainsHash(rowA.rowHash))
                            {
                                result =  rowA.ToString();
                            }

                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Files are NOT the same. Data was REMOVED.\n" + result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var addedItems = fileB.excelRows.Except(fileA.excelRows);
                        MessageBox.Show("Files are NOT the same. Data was ADDED.\n"+ addedItems.ToString());

                    }
                }
```

write now the message i get is `ExcelFileReader.ExcelRow` but i am not seeing the actual record that was removed.

I tried using the Except Operator but i got the same string message.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RoyDictus i want to returned the removed items of the compared files if items were removed or return added items if items were added to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just ToString() the excel row. It's an object, you need to go through the objects properties and convert the items that you want into a string representation. Something like the below.

```
    foreach (ExcelCell cell in excelRow.AllocatedCells)
    {
        if (cell.Value != null)
            Console.Write("{0}({1})", cell.Value, cell.Value.GetType().Name);

        Console.Write("\t");
    }
```

Comment: For ExcelCell - For me i have ExcelRow and excelRow.AllocatedCells should i calculate that previously?