# Is there a way to compare the contents (including format) of 2 excel files with SpreadsheetLight?

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetlight

I've two excel files which are both generated with SpreadsheetLight. What I need to do is to compare if both are identical or not.

With text files this would be easy as I would just generate a MD5 sum over each file but as these are .xlsx files this is not as easy as each file generation results in a slightly different file. From what I have seen already there is a solution to basically compare the content itself of 2 excel files: [Comparing two excel files for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452660/comparing-two-excel-files-for-differences)

So what is different from the basic question and answer in that Question:

1. I'm using SpreadsheetLight to generate both files
2. I need to not only compare the data inside the files but also all formats, ...

So my question there is: Is there any other way there to compare 2 excel files (especially with SpreadsheetLight involvde)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose a simple nested `for` loop would do the trick:

```
bool AreSheetsIdentical(SLDocument doc1, SLDocument doc2)
{
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats1 = doc1.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats2 = doc2.GetWorksheetStatistics();

    for (int i = 1; i < stats1.EndColumnIndex; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < stats1.EndRowIndex; j++)
        {
             if (doc1.GetCellValueAsString(i, j) != doc2.GetCellValueAsString(i, j))
                 return false;
             if (doc1.GetCellStyle(i, j) != doc2.GetCellStyle(i, j))
                 return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
}
```

You might also do some pre-checks in there using the `GetWorksheetStatistics` since if they don't have the same number of rows and columns, they're obviously not identical.