# How to compare two excel in VB.Net in less time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to generate a report by comparing two excel but its taking more time as each excel have 5000+ rows of data. To avoid these, i have created list for each column in excel ( for both excel) and trying to generate the report. Still i feel i can achieve the same by creating only one list for each excel. So my question is " `How to create only one list for one excel ( with 7 column values) and compare both the list (i.e. List1 of Excel1 and List2 of Excel2) and generate the report??`.
As i am new to VB i don't have any idea and need your suggestion for the same.
waiting for quick suggestion.. 
Below are my code snippet:

```
 For list_one = 0 To xlsheet1_file_name.Count - 1

                    For list_two = 0 To xlsheet2_file_name.Count - 1
                        Dim g1 As Integer = i1
                        If IsNothing(xlworksheet2.Range("H" & g1).Value) Then
                            If (xlsheet1_file_name(list_one) = xlsheet2_file_name(list_two)) Then
                                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                                If (source_code_1(list_one) = source_code_2(list_two)) Then
                                    If (M2CM_num_1(list_one) = M2CM_num_2(list_two)) Then
                                        If (msg_num_1(list_one) = msg_num_2(list_two)) Then
                                            Dim e1 As Integer = row_number_list_worksheet2(list_two)
                                            Console.WriteLine("the value of row =" & e1)
                                            xlworksheet2.Range("H" & e1).Value = action_1(list_one)
                                            xlworksheet2.Range("i" & e1).Value = comments_1(list_one)


                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        i1 += 1

                    Next

                Next
```

Comment: I am also looking for the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two excel files for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452660/comparing-two-excel-files-for-differences)

Comment: Hash the rows so you don't have to compare the columns, see the answer on the post I flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, minimise your usage of `DoEvents()` apart from being an awful hack, it's damned slow. You should really be spawning a background thread to handle this without locking up your main UI thread.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for your update. I need the row numbers as well when i find the similar data in both the excel.can you please  help me out in  finding the solution

Comment: @Basic thanks for the update. since i'm new i was not aware of this.