# Best Performance code for huge XLS file and compare records one by one?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, oledb, xls

I read this topic more times: [This SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452660/comparing-two-excel-files-for-differences) about compare two XLS (Excel File), I work and try on some little examples.

I want to write a best performance C# code that read two huge XLS file and compare first row of file A with all lines of file B. if first row of A not occurred in all lines of file B, list the row of A and going to next line of A.xls and again compare with all lines of file B.

Update 1:

(I do as follows):

```
DataTable dt1 = GetDataTableFromExcel(this.Directory, this.FirstFile, this.FirstFileSheetName);
dtRet = getDifferentRecords(dt1, dt2);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetName + "$]", connectionString);
```

Update 2:

My main problem occured when Xls contains 4000 records ! (Huge files)

Comment: So what code have you written and how does it perform?

Comment: @SolarMike Update one is enough?

Comment: So how does it perform? Expected time? Actual time?

Comment: It will 90% Ok with 100 or 150 records, but for large records after 50 minutes no working !

Comment: If your code is taking >50m to process 4000 rows, there is something fundamentally wrong with what you are doing (and there is not enough info in your Q to say what that is).  FWIW, 4000 rows is not huge.  I could write a vba solution to do it that runs in a few seconds.  You should be able to do much better that that in C#.

Comment: It's good to use VBA, would you please post it how we can do with VBA? it's good to convert to C#. @chrisneilsen

Comment: @LoveComplexity answered as requested

Answer (score 0):

As [requested by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5920466/lovecomplexity), here's a VBA solution.   Guessing at a few details, so OP will need to adjust to suit their specific use case

This runs for me in <2s over 4000 rows

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    Dim rw1 As Long, rw2 As Long
    Dim cl As Long
    Dim Found  As Boolean

    Const NUM_COLS_COMPARE = 1 'adjust as required

    ' Get Reference to, or open workboks
    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("NameOfBook1.xlsx")  'if already open
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\ToWorkbook2.xlsx") 'if not open

    'Get reference to sheets
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("NameOfSheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("NameOfSheet2")

    'get reference to ranges
    '  assuming data in Column A and Row 1fill whole range.  Adjust if necassary
    Set r1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), _
                       ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set r2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), _
                       ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    'Get Data into Array
    v1 = r1.Value2
    v2 = r2.Value2

    For rw1 = 1 To UBound(v1, 1)
        For rw2 = 1 To UBound(v2, 1)
            Found = False
            For cl = 1 To NUM_COLS_COMPARE
                If v1(rw1, cl) = v2(rw2, cl) Then
                    Found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Found Then Exit For
        Next rw2
        'List Found row
        If Not Found Then
            Debug.Print "No Match for " & rw1, v1(rw1, 1)
        End If
    Next rw1
End Sub
```